# How to solve Latex Error: DoxyEnumerate undefined

Tags: errors, packages

Using latex, I got this error message:

> Latex Error: Environment DoxyEnumerate undefined.

How can this be fixed?

I checked the refman.tex file, \usepackage{doxygen} is there.  Below is what refman.tex looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}  
\usepackage{a4wide}  
\usepackage{makeidx}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{multicol}  
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{textcomp}  
\usepackage{alltt}  
\usepackage{times}  
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined  
\usepackage[ps2pdf,  
            pagebackref=true,  
            colorlinks=true,  
            linkcolor=blue  
           ]{hyperref}  
\usepackage{pspicture}  
\else  
\usepackage[pdftex,  
            pagebackref=true,  
            colorlinks=true,  
            linkcolor=blue  
           ]{hyperref}  
\fi
\usepackage{doxygen}  
\makeindex  
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}  
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{titlepage}  
\vspace*{7cm}  
\begin{center}  
{\Large  Users' Guide}\\  
\vspace*{1cm}  
{\large Version 3.0}\\  
\vspace*{0.5cm}  
{\small Copyright \copyright2009,sc Ltd.}\\  
\end{center}  
\end{titlepage}  
\clearemptydoublepage  
\pagenumbering{roman}  
\tableofcontents  
\clearemptydoublepage  
\pagenumbering{arabic}  
\chapter{Introduction }  
\label{index}\hypertarget{index}{}\input{index} % here when comes to index.tex file, I got the error message.
```

In index.tex file:

The full set of E-L functions are also available for programming.
The tool kit is made up of two high-/level, shared libraries.

```
\begin{DoxyEnumerate}  
\item e\-\_\-co  
\item e\-\_\-co\-\_\-gra  
\end{DoxyEnumerate}
```

Thanks.

Comment: latex code looks like:                                            The tool kit is made up of two high-\/level, shared libraries.
\begin{DoxyEnumerate}
\item eyelink\-\_\-core
\item eyelink\-\_\-core\-\_\-graphics
\end{DoxyEnumerate}

Comment: Yes,  I guess something is missing for latex to find DoxyEnumerate and other things related to Doxygen. But I don't know what thing is missing. If it is \usepackage, what package I should add to it? Thanks.

Comment: Please read this: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @user1558064: _Please_ read the FAQ. The link to it is right at the top of the page.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build your based on the file `refman.tex`. If I guess right you did not include the right file. Anyway I think that the next line will help you:

```
\usepackage{doxygen}
```

---

Related to your update try to copy all usepackage to your main document and the content of the refman.tex into your main document. You find the start of the content with the command `\chapter`.

In my file it looks so:

```
\chapter{Namespace Index}
\input{namespaces}
\chapter{Class Index}
\input{hierarchy}
\chapter{Class Index}
\input{annotated}
\chapter{File Index}
\input{files}
\chapter{Namespace Documentation}
\input{...
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, I checked refman.tex file, \usepackage{doxygen} is listed there. Detail about the refman.tex and index.tex is given above.  What else could cause this error? Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you are not using the doxygen.sty file that doxygen generates, but maybe a customized file (or one from a very old doxygen release). Please check if this file contains the \newenvironment{DoxyEnumerate} command.

Comment: yes, this is the reason for the error message I got. Thanks. I use doxygenWizard to genearate a new one. now it works again.